# Upgrade Assistant Error: Target Project Not Found When Upgrading .NET Framework MVC to .NET 8

Tags: c#

I'm in the process of upgrading a large .NET Framework (MVC Monorails) solution to .NET 8, a transition that started initially to .NET 6 about a year ago. We've made significant progress, but there's still a lot to do.

I decided to use the Visual Studio Upgrade Assistant to facilitate the remaining work. Since we have an extensive amount of upgrade work already done, I cannot start a new project; I need to upgrade within the existing project context.

However, when I attempt to use the Upgrade Assistant on our existing project, I encounter the following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid operation context, target project was not found.
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Operations.SideBySideOperationContext.get_TargetProject() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\engine\Operations\SideBySideOperationContext.cs:line 52
   at Microsoft.UpgradeAssistant.Msbuild.Transformers.ProjectDependenciesFinalizerTransformer.<RunAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\msbuild\Transformers\Project\ProjectDependenciesFinalizerTransformer.cs:line 32
```

When I opt for creating a new project in the Upgrade Assistant, it proceeds without issues, which is not the path I want to take.

Has anyone faced a similar problem or can suggest further troubleshooting steps to resolve this context issue with the Upgrade Assistant?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.